# QtSpim Assembler: Error on stack operation with double

Tags: assembly, double, mips, spim, qtspim

i'm writing a program for class. It takes x and epsilon from the console and should retrieve an sin(x) approximation. When i run it in QtSpim i get the error:

> Unknown instruction type: 0

The error occurs here:

```
 floatsin:    addi    $sp, $sp, -64   # Frame
              sw      $ra, 64($ra)
              sw      $fp, 60($sp)
              s.d     $f0, 56($sp)
              s.d     $f4, 48($sp)
              s.d     $f20, 40($sp)
              s.d     $f8, 32($sp)
              s.d     $f10, 24($sp)
              s.d     $f14, 16($sp)
              s.d     $f18, 8($sp)        # ERROR HERE
              addi    $fp, $sp, 64
```

What could be the reason? I'm confused because till `s.d $f18` everything runs normal. Thanks for any hints!

Below the full programm:

```
.data
xinput:      .asciiz "\nPlease enter x\n"
epsinput:    .asciiz "\nPlease enter epsilon\n"
sinxoutput:  .asciiz "\nsin(x) is: "

.text

main: la    $a0, xinput
      li    $v0, 4
      syscall
      li    $v0, 7
      syscall
      mov.d $f2, $f12
      la $a0, epsinput
      li $v0, 4
      syscall
      li    $v0, 7
      syscall
      mov.d $f0, $f12
      jal   floatsin
      la    $a0, sinxoutput
      li    $v0, 4
      syscall
      li    $v0, 3
      syscall
      li    $v0, 10
      syscall

floatsin:     addi    $sp, $sp, -64   # Frame
              sw      $ra, 64($ra)
              sw      $fp, 60($sp)
              s.d     $f0, 56($sp)
              s.d     $f4, 48($sp)
              s.d     $f20, 40($sp)
              s.d     $f8, 32($sp)
              s.d     $f10, 24($sp)
              s.d     $f14, 16($sp)
              s.d     $f18, 8($sp)
              addi    $fp, $sp, 64

              li.d    $f8,  0.0   # Initialize
              li.d    $f14, 1.0
              mov.d   $f16, $f0
              li.d    $f18, 0.0

              jal     loop_p1

main_loop:    add.d   $f18, $f18, $f4
              c.lt.d  $f2, $f4
              bc1f    exit_fsin
              jal     loop_p1
              sub.d   $f18, $f18, $f4
              c.lt.d  $f2, $f4
              bc1f    exit_fsin
              jal     loop_p1
              j       main_loop


loop_p1:      add.d   $f8, $f8, $f14
              li.d    $f10, 1.0       #for (j < 2i-1)
              mov.d   $f4,  $f16
              li.d    $f20, 0.0
              add.d   $f20, $f8, $f8
              sub.d   $f20, $f20, $f14
for:          c.lt.d  $f10, $f20
              bc1f    loop_p2
              mul.d   $f4, $f4, $f16 # (x*x)
              add.d   $f10, $f10, $f14
              j       for

loop_p2:      mov.d   $f0, $f20
              move    $t0, $ra
              jal     floatfac
              div.d   $f4, $f4, $f12
              jr      $t0

exit_fsin:    mov.d   $f12, $f18     # Write in target register
              l.d     $f18, 8($sp)   # rewrite values
              l.d     $f14, 16($sp)
              l.d     $f10, 24($sp)
              l.d     $f8,  32($sp)
              l.d     $f20, 40($sp)
              l.d     $f4,  48($sp)
              l.d     $f0,  56($sp)
              lw      $fp,  60($sp)
              lw      $ra,  64($sp)
              addi    $sp, $sp, 64
              jr      $ra           # back to caller


floatfac:     addi    $sp, $sp, -28   # Frame
              sw      $fp, 28($sp)
              s.d     $f4, 24($sp)
              s.d     $f2, 16($sp)    
              s.d     $f0,  8($sp)
              addi    $fp, $sp, 28

              li.d    $f4, 0.0
              c.le.d  $f0, $f4
              bc1t    negative
              li.d    $f12, 1.0
              li.d    $f2, 1.0

while:        c.le.d  $f0, $f2       # Break condition
              bc1t    exit_floatfact
              mul.d  $f12, $f12, $f0
              sub.d   $f0, $f0, $f2
              j       while



negative:     li.d     $f12, 0.0




exit_floatfact: l.d      $f0,  8($sp)   # rewrite values
                l.d      $f2, 16($sp)
                l.d      $f4, 24($sp)
                lw       $fp, 28($sp)
                addi     $sp, $sp, 28
                jr       $ra
```

Comment: clang assembles your code just fine.  `clang -target mips mips-float.S -c` makes a `.o` which `llvm-objdump -d` can disassemble.  I don't have SPIM installed and didn't try it with MARS.  Are you saying it assembles but gives an error at runtime?  Is it possible you overwrote your code with data at runtime with a bad pointer?  Or had the stack grow until it overlapped code?  Use your debugger to check `$sp` at that point, and also to disassemble the code in memory after the error happens.

Comment: Yes it was a runtime error, Michael below pointed out the problem. But your comment was helpfull for general understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is incorrect: `sw $ra, 64($ra)`

What's happening here is that you're storing the current value of `$ra` (0x40005c) at `64($ra)`, i.e. `(0x40009c)`, thereby overwriting the instruction `s.d $f14, 16($sp)`.

What you should be doing instead is `sw $ra, 64($sp)`